# MessageConsumer/MessageProducer vs QueueSender/QueueReceiver

Tags: java, jms, xa

Is the `MessageConsumer`/`MessageProducer` the XA equivalent of `QueueSender`/`QueueReceiver`?

As far as I can understand the `MessageConsumer`/`MessageProducer` are better used in a XA context.

In my app I want to switch from `QueueConnectionFactory`, `QueueConnection`, QueueSession to their XA equivalent and for that I would need to use `MessageConsumers`/`Receivers` instead of `QueueSenders` and `QueueReceivers`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is the `MessageConsumer`/`MessageProducer` the XA equivalent of `QueueSender`/`QueueReceiver`?

No.  `QueueSender` extends `MessageProducer`, and provides some additional queue-specific methods.  It has nothing to do with XA.  The same relationship exists between `QueueReceiver` and `MessageConsumer`.

> As far as I can understand the `MessageConsumer`/`MessageProducer` are better used in a XA context.

Again, this has nothing to do with XA.  It's generally better to write to the `MessageConsumer`/`MessageProducer` interfaces in any JMS code, *unless* you specifically need the extra methods provided by `QueueSender`/`QueueReceiver`.

> In my app I want to switch from `QueueConnectionFactory`, `QueueConnection`, `QueueSession` to their XA equivalent and for that I would need to use MessageConsumers/Receivers instead of QueueSenders and QueueReceivers.

No. Whether you use XA or not has nothing to do with your choice of API interface. The XA behaviour is determined by which `QueueConnectionFactory` you obtain from the application server. Most will provide you with either an XA or a non-XA `QueueConnectionFactory`, generally on a different JNDI path, and it is up to you to obtain the appropriate one.

Once you have the correct `QueueConnectionFactory`, your application should not care whether XA is used or not.